# can I combine SSH multiplexing with ProxyJump or ProxyCommand (aka 'bastion') forwarding?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I've got a reasonably standard jump/bastion host setup, where I have to SSH from `A` into `C`,  via `B` :

`Host A --> Host B --> Host C`

I've gotten SSH multiplexing set up, which dramatically reduces the time it takes to open a subsequent session from A->B: it cuts this from ~2.5sec down to less than 0.5sec.  Is there a way to extend this multiplexing such that I can get the benefits for BOTH hops?

I've tried putting the equivalent `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist` stanzas in the ssh config file on host B, but this didn't help.  It's not clear to me that it SHOULD help, as I can't figure out whether the intermediate host actually launches a new SSH session or merely carries the data somewhat transparently?

Current `.ssh/config` file looks something like this:

```
Host C
        User myname
        ControlMaster auto
        ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
        ControlPersist 3600
        ProxyJump myname@HOST_B_IP_ADDR:22
        LogLevel ERROR
```